# How to be able to pass variable to rules in gitlab ci pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I want to use rules in my GitLab CI pipeline to be able to check if commit is commited from desired branch and if I have any fixable issues in image that I pushed on Harbor registry.

I push that image to registry and do scan of that image on Harbor registry, then get those results in previous stages and now I want to be able to check if I have any fixable issues in that image, if I have I would like to create that job to be manual but to leave the possibility to continue with execution of pipeline and other stages that come after this. If I don't find any of those issues ( I don't have it in my APIs output form Harbor ) I just set that variable to 0 and I wat to continue with execution of pipeline normaly. That varibale for fixable issues in pipeline is called FIXABLE, I tried many ways to assign value to this varibale so rules can be able to read value of that varibale but non of these worked. I will post mu latest work down below so that anyone, who has an idea or advice can look at this. Any help would mean a lot to me. I know that rules are created immediately after the pipeline itself is created so at this moment I am not really sure how can I deal with this.
Thanks in advance!

I have added value of 60 to varibale FINAL_FIXABLE to check if job would run manualy.
Issue is that only this job  `procession results (dev branch, case one)` is running even though FINAL_FIXABLE is set to 60.

After I do build and push of image, those are the stages in pipeline related to this problem:

```
get results (dev branch):
  stage: Results of scanning image
  image: alpine
  variables:
    RESULTS: ""
    STATUS: ""
    SEVERITY: ""
    FIXABLE: ""
  before_script:
    - apk update && apk upgrade
    - apk --no-cache add curl
    - apk add jq
    - chmod +x ./scan-script.sh
  script:
    - 'RESULTS=$(curl -H "Authorization: Basic `echo -n ${HARBOR_USER}:${HARBOR_PASSWORD} | base64`" -X GET "https://myregistry/projects/myproject/artifacts/latest?page=1&page_size=10&with_tag=true&with_label=true&with_scan_overview=true&with_signature=true&with_immutable_status=true")'
    - STATUS=$(./scan-script.sh "STATUS" "$RESULTS")
    - SEVERITY=$(./scan-script.sh "SEVERITY" "$RESULTS")
    - FIXABLE=$(./scan-script.sh "FIXABLE" "$RESULTS")
    # - echo "$FIXABLE">fixableValue.txt
    - echo "Printing the results of the image scanning process on Harbor registry:"
    - echo "status of scan:$STATUS"
    - echo "severity of scan:$SEVERITY"
    - echo "number of fixable issues:$FIXABLE"
    - echo "For more information of scan results please visit Harbor registry!"
    - FINAL_FIXABLE=$FIXABLE
    - echo $FINAL_FIXABLE
    - FINAL_FIXABLE="60"
    - echo $FINAL_FIXABLE
    - echo "$FINAL_FIXABLE">fixableValue.txt
  only:
     refs:
       - dev
       - some-test-branch
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - fixableValue.txt

get results (other branches):
  stage: Results of scanning image
  dependencies:
    - prep for build (other branches)
  image: alpine
  variables:
    RESULTS: ""
    STATUS: ""
    SEVERITY: ""
    FIXABLE: ""
  before_script:
    - apk update && apk upgrade
    - apk --no-cache add curl
    - apk add jq
    - chmod +x ./scan-script.sh
  script:
    - LATEST_TAG=$(cat tags.txt)
    - echo "Latest tag is $LATEST_TAG"
    - 'RESULTS=$(curl -H "Authorization: Basic `echo -n ${HARBOR_USER}:${HARBOR_PASSWORD} | base64`" -X GET "https://myregistry/myprojects/artifacts/"${LATEST_TAG}"?page=1&page_size=10&with_tag=true&with_label=true&with_scan_overview=true&with_signature=true&with_immutable_status=true")'
    - STATUS=$(./scan-script.sh "STATUS" "$RESULTS")
    - SEVERITY=$(./scan-script.sh "SEVERITY" "$RESULTS")
    - FIXABLE=$(./scan-script.sh "FIXABLE" "$RESULTS")
    # - echo "$FIXABLE">fixableValue.txt
    - echo "Printing the results of the image scanning process on Harbor registry:"
    - echo "status of scan:$STATUS"
    - echo "severity of scan:$SEVERITY"
    - echo "number of fixable issues:$FIXABLE"
    - echo "For more information of scan results please visit Harbor registry!"
    - FINAL_FIXABLE=$FIXABLE
    - echo $FINAL_FIXABLE
    - FINAL_FIXABLE="60"
    - echo $FINAL_FIXABLE
    - echo "$FINAL_FIXABLE">fixableValue.txt
  only:
      refs:
        - master
        - /^(([0-9]+)\.)?([0-9]+)\.x/
        - rc
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - fixableValue.txt

procession results (dev branch, case one):
  stage: Scan results processing
  dependencies:
    - get results (dev branch)
  image: alpine
  script:
    - FINAL_FIXABLE=$(cat fixableValue.txt)
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    - echo $FINAL_FIXABLE
  rules:
    - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "some-test-branch") && ($FINAL_FIXABLE=="0")
      when: always

procession results (dev branch, case two):
  stage: Scan results processing
  dependencies:
    - get results (dev branch)
  image: alpine
  script:
    - FINAL_FIXABLE=$(cat fixableValue.txt)
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    - echo $FINAL_FIXABLE
  rules:
    - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "some-test-branch") && ($FINAL_FIXABLE!="0")
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true

procession results (other branch, case one):
  stage: Scan results processing
  dependencies:
    - get results (other branches)
  image: alpine
  script:
    - FINAL_FIXABLE=$(cat fixableValue.txt)
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    - echo $FINAL_FIXABLE
  rules:
    - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "rc" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ "/^(([0-9]+)\.)?([0-9]+)\.x/") && ($FINAL_FIXABLE=="0")
      when: always

procession results (other branch, case two):
  stage: Scan results processing
  dependencies:
    - get results (other branches)
  image: alpine
  script:
    - FINAL_FIXABLE=$(cat fixableValue.txt)
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    - echo $FINAL_FIXABLE
  rules:
    - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "rc" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ "/^(([0-9]+)\.)?([0-9]+)\.x/") && ($FINAL_FIXABLE!="0")
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use these methods for controlling whether jobs run with `rules:` because **rules are evaluated at pipeline creation time** and cannot be changed once the pipeline is created.

Your best option to dynamically control pipeline configuration like this would probably be [dynamic child pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/parent_child_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines).

---

As a side note, to set environment variables for subsequent jobs, you can [use `artifacts:reports:dotenv`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsreportsdotenv). When this special artifact is passed to subsequent stages/jobs, the variables in the dotenv file will be available in the job, as if it were set in `environment:`

```yaml
stages:
  - one
  - two

first:
  stage: one
  script: # create dotenv file with variables to pass
    - echo "VAR_NAME=foo" >> "myvariables.env"
  artifacts:
    reports: # create report to pass variables to subsequent jobs
      dotenv: "myvariables.env"

second:
  stage: two
  script: # variables from dotenv artifact will be in environment automatically
    - echo "${VAR_NAME}" # foo
```

You are doing basically the same thing with your `.txt` artifact, which works effectively the same way, but this works with less script steps. One key difference is that this can allow for somewhat more dynamic control and it ***will*** apply for some other job configuration keys that use environment variables. For example, you can [set `environment:url` dynamically](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/index.html#set-dynamic-environment-urls-after-a-job-finishes) this way.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions provided.
I tried for a couple of days to solve my use case with the help of GitLab parent-child feature but I couldn't because there is currently a known issue with transferring artifacts from parent to child pipeline and there is no workarounds for this problem that can help me at the moment. Definitely thanks for the help, I learned a lot by researching this topic.